# Are C# readonly field's allowed to be modify outside of the class?

Tags: c#

I have a `readonly` object field that I set via a constructor parameter. If I modify the object, the field inside the class will also change, I guess it's a call by reference. Is there any way to do this better/prevent it?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Product p = new Product() { Name="New" };
    Store s = new Store(p);
    p.Name = "MODIFY!";
    MessageBox.Show(s.Show());//MODIFY!
}

public class Store
{
    private readonly Product product;

    public Store(Product product)
    {
        this.product = product;
    }

    public string Show()
    {
        return this.product.Name;
    }
}

public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: declare the variable as `const`

Comment: @SouvikGhosh reference type fields cannot be marked `const` unless a null reference is assigned, which defeats the point here.

Comment: No matter what the solution, anything other than const can be changed with reflection. Everything else is just compiler rules.

Comment: `readonly` is *shallow* immutability (only applies to the variable it's applied to). What I think you're looking for is *deep* immutability (applies to the variable it's applied to and any fields of the referenced type, recursively), which isn't currently available as a language feature.

Answer (score 12):

What you store in your `readonly` field is a **reference**. And that reference of course is readonly and never changed. But the content of the *referenced* object can still be changed.

Since `Product` seems to be a data-holding class, one approach might be to simply copy the content into a new instance:

```
public class Store
{
    private readonly Product product;

    public Store(Product product)
    {
        // Create a new Product instance that only this Store instance
        // knows about
        this.product = new Product { Name = product.Name };
    }
}
```

Now the content of `Store.product` cannot be changed from outside as long as you don't export this instance.
But note that code *inside* the `Store` class may still be able to change the content.

Comment: While the OP does mention `object`, a possible alternative would be to declare it as `struct`. This will mean the data gets copied in but assumes the data structure is simple.

Comment: @DiskJunky yes, making `Product` a `struct` is a good possibility. But I thought that would be a bigger change to OP's code (don't know how that `Product` _class_ is used already elsewhere).

Comment: @DiskJunky making it a `struct` *just* to get easy copying is not a good idea, it would change too much. if the OP wants a copy of the object instead of a reference to the same object, then he needs to make a copy.

Comment: @DaveCousineau I absolutely agree. I was just calling it out as an option if the structure was a simple enough one. It's unclear if this is new or existing code.

Comment: @DiskJunky I suspect you are mixing up immutability (that what you'd want in this case) and `struct`... `struct` does not solve problem that any mutable object directly or indirectly referenced that way can be modified... I.e. `struct X { SomeMutableClass Y {get;} }` would still have the same problem, just with one more dot.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want `product` inside of `Store` to change if you change the original instance, you have to make a copy before assigning it to the field:

```
public Store(Product product)
{
    this.product = new Product() {Name = product.Name};
}
```

Alterantively, you could make `Product` a struct. Structs are always copied when passed to a method, and *not* passed by reference:

```
public struct Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is creating an immutable version of Product:

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Immutable ToImmutable() => new Immutable(this);

    public class Immutable
    {
         public Immutable(Product product) { Name = product.Name; }
         public string Name { get; }
    }
}
```

And now,

```
public class Store
{
    private readonly Product.Immutable product;

    public Store(Product product)
    {
        this.product = product.ToImmutable();
    }

    public string Show()
    {
        return this.product.Name;
    }
}
```

Benefits? No one can mess around with `product` inside `Store`.